# Docker swarm secret not working correctly in node.js api (mongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to get my mongo_username and mongo_password in a swarm secret, but for some reason they are converted? I get this error in the container log

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/saslprep/index.js:99
    throw new Error(
    ^

Error: Prohibited character, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4013#section-2.3
    at saslprep (/usr/src/app/node_modules/saslprep/index.js:99:11)
    at continueScramConversation (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:126:36)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:111:5
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at processIncomingData (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:353:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:303:12)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:713:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:278:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:217:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

I added the secret like this

```
echo admin | docker secret create mongo_username -
echo totallySecurePassword23456789 | docker secret create mongo_password -
```

and when i log those two secrets in my DB connect function like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); // For connection to DB

const {
  MONGO_USERNAME,
  MONGO_PASSWORD,
  MONGO_HOSTNAME,
  MONGO_PORT,
  MONGO_DATABASE_NAME,
} = process.env;

console.log(MONGO_USERNAME);
console.log(MONGO_PASSWORD);
console.log(MONGO_HOSTNAME);
console.log(MONGO_PORT);
console.log(MONGO_DATABASE_NAME);

const url = `mongodb://${MONGO_USERNAME}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DATABASE_NAME}?retryWrites=true$w=majority`;

console.log(url);

const connectDB = async () => {
  const conn = await mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline.bold);
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

They show up correctly as:

```
admin
totallySecurePassword23456789
host.docker.internal
27020
mainDB
```

and yet the url which is made which is supposed to look like `mongodb://admin:totallySecurePassword23456789@host.docker.internal:27020/mainDB?retryWrites=true$w=majority`

shows up as `@host.docker.internal:27020/mainDB?retryWrites=true$w=majority`
And this ofcourse makes the connection fail

the hostname, port and database_name work fine because these are defined as normal environment variables

Any help would be really appreciated, and if more info is needed please let me know!

Edit 1:
Here is the docker-compose file i use to run docker stack:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  main:
    image: main:5.0.0
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo_username
      - MONGO_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo_password
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=host.docker.internal
      - MONGO_PORT=27020
      - MONGO_DATABASE_NAME=mainDB
    secrets:
      - mongo_username
      - mongo_password
    networks:
      - main-net
    ports:
      - "80:3001"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        window: 60s
networks:
  main-net:
    driver: overlay

secrets:
  mongo_username:
    external: true
  mongo_password:
    external: true
```

Edit 2:
Fixed the compose file missing the _FILE behind the username and password

Comment: Can you provide commands you used to deploy MongoDB and your application? Or if you used `docker stack`, please, provide your docker-compose file

Comment: @n0nvme My mongoDB is running outside of docker thats why the host.docker.internal. I do indeed use docker stack, i will add the docker-compose file

Comment: Are you sure that your MongoDB runs on port `27020`? The default one is `27017`

Comment: @n0nvme Yep, I do get a reaction from the db but the reaction confuses me, it basically tells me that the authentication failed because of a user that does not exist. This is because the URL it uses to connect is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of investigating i found out i was having this problem https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/701, with no good fix found i settled on editing the entrypoint i was using  (https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults/blob/main/docker-entrypoint.sh) so it removed the end of line stuff before setting it as a environment variable by using
`export "$var"="${val//[$'\t\r\n ']}"`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use **gnu bash**. If you use [**echo**](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-echo) shell builtin without **-n** option, it automatically adds new line to provided string.

Try these:

```
echo -n admin | docker secret create mongo_username -
echo -n totallySecurePassword23456789 | docker secret create mongo_password -
```

---

If you want to check your secret value whether includes new line, execute the following command on the machine where your docker cli resides:

```
docker container exec <your_container_name or id> cat -e /run/secrets/<your_secret_name>
```

If this command returns your value followed by $ symbol then we can conclude that new line character was appended while you were creating secret.

**Note**: I presume your container is a linux container. Also, be sure your container is in **running** state and its PATH environment variable must include the directory path where **cat** binary reside.